# Unable to convert Gson JsonObject to POJO class

Tags: java, gson, pojo

I have a simple POJO class `Defect`:

```java
    import lombok.Getter;
    import lombok.Setter;
    import lombok.ToString;

    @Setter
    @Getter
    @ToString
    public class Defect {

        private String formattedId;
        private String fixedInBuild;
        private String foundInBuild;
        private String verifiedInBuild;
        private String state;
        private String resolution;
        private String submittedBy;
        private String priority;
        private String severity;    
    }
```

And I am trying to convert a `Gson.JsonObject` to `Defect`. The `JsonObject` looks like this:

[image]

I want to store only specific fields hence not all added in the POJO.

But `new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(object, Defect.class)` returns a `Defect` object with all `null` values. What is wrong here?

Comment: Looks like the elements in the Json itself have different names (different case) than the fields in the POJO. You should set a naming policy in the `GsonBuilder` before the `create`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json elements are different from the POJO members as a result proper mapping is not happening.
Please  annotate formattedId as

```
@SerializedName("FormattedID")
private String formattedId;
```

to make formattedId work.